# Line plotting on small dataset

Tags: r, r-plotly

i have this small dataset that i need to plot with plotly. Im struggling with it :/
[image: dataset]
Im looking to have 3 colored lines (each line for each of the rows (1,2,3). The x axis needs to be the column names and the Y axis represents each one of the numeric values.

My code so far looks wrong

```
plot_ly (x = colnames(a), y = a[1], type = "scatter" ,mode = "lines" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is your desired plot, but it sounded closest to your description. I adapted a few columns of your data to describe.

The plot will be easier if data is in longer form with `pivot_longer`. Also easier if you add row numbers to your data so you can plot one line for each row number.

Since `plotly` will plot your xaxis categories alphabetically, you will want to relevel your `name` factor (name is your column names) to order of your columns.

In your `plot_ly` statement, use `split` to plot by row number.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

a %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = colnames(a))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~name, y = ~value, split = ~rn, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
```

**Output**

[image: plotly plot with 3 lines]

**Data**

```
a <- data.frame(
  N_of_Brands = c(-.4, .8, -.4),
  Brand_Runs = c(-.26, .70, -.75),
  Total_Volume = c(-.69, .15, -.015),
  No_of_Trans = c(-.81, .45, -.35)
)
```

Comment: thanks ben. it helped me a lot in order to start the plot. i was so way lost